# PHP MySQL PDO TextArea Where clause with condition checks

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, textarea

I have a page as shown in the screenshot below. The idea is to enter the bus number and the list of all stops on a particular route, one per line.

[image: My Add Route Page]

The stops are already stored in a database table called 'stops' I need the ID of each stop from the textarea. My current code only gets the ID of the last stop in the textarea. I feel like I am missing something. 'busnumber' is my textfield and 'busroute' is my textarea. I would appreciate if anyone can point me out on what I need to change in order to get the ID of each stop entered in the textarea as an array. Thanks for your time in advance.

```
try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            if(isset($_POST["busnumber"]) && isset($_POST["busroute"])){

            $stops = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["busroute"]);
            $stopsArray = '"' . implode('","', $stops) . '"';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM stops WHERE stop_name IN ($stopsArray)";
            echo $sql."</br>";
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $results = $query->fetchAll();
            foreach($results as $result){
            echo $result['stop_id'].' '.$result['stop_name'].'</br>';
            }
            }

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
```

}

**UPDATE 1**
I changed the code as follows

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        if(isset($_POST["busnumber"], $_POST["busroute"])){

    $stops = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["busroute"]);

    foreach($stops as $stop){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stops WHERE stop_name = '".$stop."'";
        $statement = $conn->query($sql);
        echo $sql.'</br>';
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $results = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo $result['stop_id'].' '.$result['stop_name'];
        }
        $statement = null;

    }
        }
```

and still get the same output, it only gives me the ID of the last item inside the textarea
[image: The error is still here]

Comment: `print_r($result)` inside foreach loop and check what it return!!

Comment: It returns Array ( [stop_id] => 3 [stop_name] => 16TH ROAD ) @Saty

Comment: means it return only one result . Run your query direct into phpmyadmin and check how many rows return by your query!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FIXED THE ERROR. The solution for anyone out there is simple, the PHP explode function was used to split the contents of a textarea into separate lines but it doesn't work if you use explode() with PHP_EOL. PHP EOL tells you the server's newline character from what I understand. I used the preg_split instead to perform the splitting and it works on both my localhost that runs on Windows and my server that runs on Linux. Thank you everyone for your help!!!

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                if(isset($_POST["busnumber"], $_POST["busroute"])){
                    $stops = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $_POST['busroute']);
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM stops WHERE stop_name LIKE :stop';
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    foreach($stops as $stop){
                        $statement->bindValue(':stop', $stop);
                        $statement->execute();
                        while($result = $statement->fetch()){
                            echo $result['stop_id'].' '.$result['stop_name'].'</br>';
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Oh, so it was the PHP thing. Glad you solved the problem now :)

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that you have working code displayed above. I'm sorry for giving answers before (see history if ya want) that are already there above (*haha). Here, I've updated  the code of yours (the first one). I changed the part where you display the result:

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        if(isset($_POST["busnumber"]) && isset($_POST["busroute"])){
            $stops = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["busroute"]);
            $stopsArray = '"' . implode('","', $stops) . '"';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM stops WHERE stop_name IN ($stopsArray)";
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();

            if ($query->rowCount() > 0){
                while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<br/>'.$row['stop_id'].' '.$row['stop_name'];
                }
            }else{
                echo "No records found...";
            }
        }
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

**Note:** As I have read some tutorials, using while loop is conventional than `fetchAll()`.

Comment: will try this out and upvote you if it works :) thanks for your answer

Comment: Looks like you used a mysqli method  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_result() in C:\wamp64\www\reach\addroute.php on line 59 :) let me find an alternative

Comment: @PirateApp Oops! Sorry, the query fetched `stop_id` twice. I've updated the answer, try it again.

Comment: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_result() in C:\wamp64\www\reach\addroute.php on line 59 There doesnt seem to be a bind_result method as far as PDO is concerned...

Comment: @PirateApp Oops! Sorry again, I'm being paranoid for I mixed PDO with Mysqli *lol*. I've updated the answer again, let me know if it works now.

Comment: I just discovered something!!! Its not the problem with the code at all. It is something else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672808/mysql-returns-different-number-of-rows-on-localhost-vs-live-server-for-the-same

Comment: @PirateApp `fetchAll()` is not always the solution for fetching multiple data. It is more conventional to use while loop. If the code I provided above is still not working, maybe there's compatibility issue in your local and live databases.

Answer (score 3):

Your db structure could help to give you a more precise info. Since it is lacking, I am going to speculate over it a little just to give you an idea.

Each bus (route) has several stops. That means there must be a foreign key defined in stops table and it points to route table.

In order to select all stops from stops table on a given route, what you need to do is to modify your select statement as follows:

Semantic code

```
SELECT * from stops where stops.routeId = <aGivenRouteId>
```

or

```
SELECT * from stops where stops.routeId in (an Array Of Route IDs)
```

Keep in mind that second form is slower.

I hope it makes sense to you.

**__UPDATE__**

If this is the case, there might be a many to many relationship. If this is the case, look for another table which connects stops and routes. That table should contain just route_id and stop_id in order to associate them to each other. From that table, you can select stop_ids on a given route, and then from stops table you can get names of the stops.

Hope it helps.

**__UPDATE2__**

Oh I see. You may need to modify your screen a bit. Something like this:

```
+Add Route-----------------------------------------+
|Bus Number                                        |
|__________                                        |
|                                                  |
|Stops In This Route              All Stops        |
+--------------------------+-+--+------------------+
|Stop 2                    |x|  |Stop 1            |
|Stop 5                    |x|  |Stop 2            |
|Stop 9                    |x|<<|Stop 3            |
|                            |  |Stop 4           V|
+--------------------------+-+--+------------------+
|Add Route                                         |
+----------------------------+--+------------------+
```

In All Stops part, you can show all the stops in DB (in your stops table). For stops in this route part, I suggest you to create another table where you associate stops and routes, basically a table containing stop_id and route_id.

Would it work for you this way?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this whole page exists to add routes, the stops table only has a stop_id and stop_name, There are 2400 stops stored currently with a unique id for each. I would like to be able to add a route quickly by letting a person type each stop name on a new line inside the text area , get the id of each stop and add them to a route table where bus number will act as the route id, followed by the name of the stop and the stop order.

Comment: I dont have a route_id yet, only when I click the add route button, a new route id will be generated with the bus number and the stop id of all the stops from the text area

Comment: hi @Alp thanks for your updates, here is what I am trying to do, I have the list of stops with stop_id and stop_name for each. I want to add routes to the db. The route table has a route_id, stop_id and stop_order where the route_id is not unique, If a bus no 8 goes from A to B the route table will have 8, A, 0 and 8, B, 1 as the route_id, stop_id and stop_order. I want to add routes from the text area to simplify work. I add say 40 stop names in the text area, it automatically gets the ids for each and adds them to the route table. I am stuck at the part where I fetch id for each line

Comment: I am confused with your terminology to be honest. Do you use text area for route names or stop names? You seem to use these names interchangeably as "I want to add routes from the text area to simplify work. I add say 40 stop names in the text area,". Plus I think you are trying to do 3 things at once: 1) adding stops to the stops table 2) assigning stops to each route 3) Order stops on the route. Think simple, do simple, and implement it step by step. Thus your confusion.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have stop names in my database, i am trying to add routes by using those stop names, I have a text area to let a person enter 40 stop names and the page will create a route between these stops

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113495/discussion-between-alp-and-pirateapp).

Comment: Not yet @Alp i tried everything. opening a bounty on this question now

Answer (score 1):

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset",$user,$pass);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);         

if(isset($_POST["busnumber"], $_POST["busroute"]))
{
                $stops = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/$_POST['busroute']);
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM stops WHERE stop_name LIKE :stop';
                $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
                foreach($stops as $stop){
                    $statement->bindValue(':stop', $stop);
                    $statement->execute();
                    while($result = $statement->fetch())
                  {
                     echo $result['stop_id'].' '.$result['stop_name'].'</br>';                        
                  }

}
```