# MySQL Returns different number of rows on localhost vs live server for the same code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a simple form that needs a list of stops in the textarea and returns an id for each on the right hand side. This is my screenshot on localhost...I have the same table names, column names, number of records on both localhost and live server.
[image: My page on localhost]
Here's the screenshot of the same page with same query on live server...
[image: My page on live server]

Here's the code I am using on both pages

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
                if(isset($_POST["busnumber"], $_POST["busroute"])){

                    $stops = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["busroute"]);
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM stops WHERE stop_name LIKE :stop';
                    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach($stops as $stop){
                        $statement->bindValue(':stop', $stop);
                        $statement->execute();
                        $results = $statement->fetchAll();
                        foreach($results as $result){
                            echo $result['stop_id'].' '.$result['stop_name']."</br>";
                        }

                    }
                }
```

As you can see, it returns the ID of the last row only on the live server. Can someone please tell me how this is possible and what I am missing?

**EDIT 1**

Notice what happens when I reverse the data entered in the text area
The localhost shows both the ids now
[image: The localhost after reversing the rows]

Guess what the server shows after reversing? Only the LAST ROW!
[image: What server shows after reversing the rows]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need setFetchMode(). In the time I've used PDO I always had the best results with just using bindParam() and fetch() with the most default setup of PDO, which means just setting the errormode to exception and charset to utf8 like this:

```
 try
    {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db_name, $user, $password);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die("ERROR ". $e->getMessage());
    }

    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Fetching any results like this

```
while($r = $statement->fetch())
{
    echo $r['id'];
}
```

Any time when someone has used a different set up, I've noticed they've faced problems.

Try this, perhaps.

Comment: Just tried it, still the same, everything works great on the localhost but on the server it only returns the data for the last item inside the textarea

Comment: You could debug the array from the textfield with print_r to see if it actually gets all the entries correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Please check your live db via phpmyadmin if you have access and from phpmyadmin run your queries like you are running it from php code. May be you have some restrictions of mysql or php on live. And also check your db versions on localhost and live with php versions too. Let me know the results of phpmyadmin queries thanks!

Comment: I would have known if it was that simple, I am not a newbie programmer but thanks for the answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing the problem. I don't really think if this answer is correct. So please pardon me in advance.

`PDOStatement::fetchAll()` returns an array that consists of all the rows returned by the query. From this fact we can make two conclusions:

1. This function should not be used, if many rows has been selected. In
   such a case conventional while loop ave to be used, fetching rows
   one by one instead of getting them all into array at once. "Many"
   means more than it is suitable to be shown on the average web page.
2. This function is mostly useful in a modern web application that
   never outputs data right away during fetching, but rather passes it
   to template.

> Source: [PDO Tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Answer (score 0):

I FIXED the error. I have answered it in detail on a different post and I am linking to that post from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560463/php-mysql-pdo-textarea-where-clause-with-condition-checks/37676792#37676792) Thank you all for your time and answers